# Blocking netty IO using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, netty

I'm trying to get the body of (json) of a http response using netty.IO in scala.(blocking, not async)

Most examples and stuff I find is Java and I can't seem to find a way to "just get the http body" of the response back. I always end up with the response code or a .toString of an object that isn't a body.

below what I have so far

```
def getRestContentFromNetty(url:String) : String ={
//    IO.netty!

    val response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK);
    response.headers().set(Names.CONTENT_TYPE, accept_val).set(Names.AUTHORIZATION, basic_auth)

  val bbuf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer("{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"calc.add\",\"params\":[1,2],\"id\":1}", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  response.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_LENGTH, bbuf.readableBytes());
 val q = response.content().clear().writeBytes(bbuf);
  logInfo(response.getStatus.toString)// -> this logs "200 OK", so the response seems good.

  q.toString

  }
```

This returns "UnpooledHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 59, cap: 64)" and not the body

What is the major concept that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the ByteBuf as a String you would use:

`q.toString(Charset)`